# Prevent log data loss with FluentBit

Tags: amazon-eks, fluent-bit, amazon-opensearch

I am new to fluentbit and need few suggestions for our logging solution for EKS.
I am planning to achieve the below setup.  EKS [app logs] -> Fluent Bit -> Amazon opensearch.

In this scenario, how does one build a lossless logging solution.
I am concerned about the below events.

a) If the fluentbit daemon crashes. Is there a recommended memory/cpu limits for fluentbit daemon. Are there any published benchmarks that one can refer to.

b) If the opensearch cluster is unavailable/crashed or overwhelmed, will the fluentbit output plugin retry sending these logs? Are there any settings to configure this retry?

c)  One of the recommendation in the documentation to deal with backpressure is to make the storage.type as filesystem for the input plugin and keep the storage.pause_on_chunks_overlimit as off.
Also these settings 'storage.path' should be set to filesystem in all plugins, input, service and output? Is my understanding correct?

Thank you for reading and I appreciate any suggestions/guidance.